# It is inserted using existing data. Why is a new row created?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to fetch data from an existing table. However, when I update it, it creates a new row containing that data.

Below is the source code.

(ProductInfo --JPA)

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

public ProductInfo() {

}

public ProductInfo(String productType, String productSize, String productBios, String productCpu, String productDate, String productFac, String productHdd, String productNum, String productOs, String productRam, String productResolution, String productSn, String productSsd, String productSsdType, String productSecurity, boolean productUseYn) {
    this.productType = productType;
    this.productBios = productBios;
    this.productCpu = productCpu;
    this.productDate = productDate;
    this.productFac = productFac;
    this.productHdd = productHdd;
    this.productNum = productNum;
    this.productOs = productOs;
    this.productRam = productRam;
    this.productResolution = productResolution;
    this.productSn = productSn;
    this.productSsd = productSsd;
    this.productSsdType = productSsdType;
    this.productSecurity = productSecurity;
    this.productUseYn = productUseYn;
    this.productSize = productSize;

}
```

(Users --JPA)

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<ProductInfo> productInfos = new HashSet<>();

public User() {
}

public User(String username, String email, String password, boolean delYn) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.delYn = delYn;
}
```

[users Table column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDo46.png)

[productInfo Table column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOej6.png)

(product Controller)

```
@PutMapping(value = {"/products/{id}", "/productSetting/{id}", "/productList/{id}"})
public ResponseEntity<ProductInfo> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody ProductInfo productInfo) {
  Optional<ProductInfo> productData = productInfoRepository.findById(id);

  if (productData.isPresent()) {
    ProductInfo _ProductInfo = productData.get();
    _ProductInfo.setUser(productInfo.getUser());
    _ProductInfo.setProductType(productInfo.getProductType());
    _ProductInfo.setProductSize(productInfo.getProductSize());
    _ProductInfo.setProductBios(productInfo.getProductBios());
    _ProductInfo.setProductCpu(productInfo.getProductCpu());
    _ProductInfo.setProductDate(productInfo.getProductDate());
    _ProductInfo.setProductFac(productInfo.getProductFac());
    _ProductInfo.setProductHdd(productInfo.getProductHdd());
    _ProductInfo.setProductNum(productInfo.getProductNum());
    _ProductInfo.setProductOs(productInfo.getProductOs());
    _ProductInfo.setProductRam(productInfo.getProductRam());
    _ProductInfo.setProductResolution(productInfo.getProductResolution());
    _ProductInfo.setProductSecurity(productInfo.getProductSecurity());
    _ProductInfo.setProductSn(productInfo.getProductSn());
    _ProductInfo.setProductSsd(productInfo.getProductSsd());
    _ProductInfo.setProductSsdType(productInfo.getProductSsdType());
    _ProductInfo.setProductUseYn(productInfo.isProductUseYn());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(productInfoRepository.save(_ProductInfo), HttpStatus.OK);
  } else {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }
}
```

(vue.js script)

```
updateProductUserAdd(status) {
  var data = {
    id:this.currentProductInfo.id,
    productUseYn: status,
    user: {
      username: this.currentUser.username
    }
  };
  ProductInfoDataService.update(this.currentProductInfo.id, data, {id: this.currentUser.id, data})
    .then(response => {
      this.currentProductInfo = response.data;
      this.currentProductInfo = status;
      console.log(this.currentProductInfo);
      console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
},
```

For example I select a user named test1 in the selected product and I want to add only the username of that user. Running the code creates a new row where the user has the original row for test1, the user name test1 and the rest of the data is null.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `productInfo.getUser()` has `identity` set i.e. it has id mapped to tables otherwise hibernate does not know whether the `user` object is new or old one.

Comment: Among the sources of the productInfo table,

public User getUser() {
      return user;
  }
  public void setUser(User user) {
      this.user = user;
  }
There is. Are you talking about this? 
Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: check this block `_ProductInfo.setUser(productInfo.getUser());` over here `productInfo` is the data being submitted and if the user returned from here doesn't have id mapped to user table then hibernate or JPA doesn't know it's a new or existing entity and if the id is missing then it assume that it's new instance of object and create new records